# Problem with compiling module: "No rule to make target"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, make

I created source of simple module for kernel named example1.c

```
  #include linux/module.h

 static int __init _init_(void)
 {
 printk(KERN_INFO"Hello");
 return 0;
 }

 static void __exit _exit_(void)
 {


 printk(KERN_INFO"bye\n");
 }

 module_init(_init_);
 module_exit(_exit_);
```

After that I want to complie this to create object file(I mean example1.o) in this way

```
gcc -Wall -o example1.c example1
```

But I can't do that and I getting this error

```
example1: file not recognized: file format not recognized
```

Comment: I have changed order (I mean example1 with example1.c) but still have the same error ( example1.c : No such file or directory and fatal error: no input files).

Comment: Please remember about <linux/module.h> because I can't write brackets(Idk why). But except that code seems to be good.

Comment: If I using make example.o I get make: *** No rule to make target 'examle.o' Stop.

Comment: command file example1.c show " cann't open 'example.c' (No such file or directory) but command file example1 show C source, ASCII text.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. I have bad name of file, I renamed from example1 to example1.c.

Comment: But when I want to compile this file I have another problem, a lot of bugs like required '=' or ';' before _init_. When I create Makefile and use command make, now I have object file, kernel files and etc I don't know why is that.

Answer (score 0):

When I output to `exampleone` instead of `example1` like this: `gcc example1.c -o exampleone` I stop getting

```
gcc: error: gcc: No such file or directory
gcc: error: example1: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
```

I got these errors when compiling your code myself:

```
example1.c:1:11: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
    1 |  #include linux/module.h
      |           ^~~~~
example1.c:3:20: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘_init_’
    3 |  static int __init _init_(void)
      |                    ^~~~~~
example1.c:9:21: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘_exit_’
    9 |  static void __exit _exit_(void)
      |                     ^~~~~~
example1.c:16:2: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
   16 |  module_init(_init_);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~
example1.c:16:2: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘module_init’ [-Wimplicit-int]
example1.c:16:2: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
example1.c:17:2: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
   17 |  module_exit(_exit_);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~
example1.c:17:2: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘module_exit’ [-Wimplicit-int]
example1.c:17:2: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
```

Let me know if this fixes your problem. If it does not, let me know and I will delete this answer.
One last thing, make sure you are in the right directory in the terminal.